# Detect integer value inside a string, alter it and leave it in the same place within the string

Tags: php, laravel, string, integer, trim

Lets say we have a string that looks something like this:

`10.000 some text 5.200 some text 5.290 some text`

What i want to do is to remove the last zero (if it is present) from all of the present int values within the given string, the result should be:

`10.00 some text 5.20 some text 5.29 some text`

Is there a convenient way to do it? Strings are mostly more complicated then the example given, so I'm looking for a way to detect an integer value, check if it ends with a 0, trim that zero and leave the altered integer value at the same place inside the string.

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions yet? If not, start looking into them. https://regex101.com/r/8CR3mD/1 - if you use a pattern like this with `preg_replace`, and replace the match with the content of the capturing group, you should be as good as there already.

Comment: Thank you Cbroe, your solution is pretty much what I needed, as well as the answer I accepted. Enjoy your day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = '10.000 some text 5.200 some text 5.290 some text';

$result = preg_replace('(0(?=[^0-9.]))', '', $text);

echo $result;   // Output: 10.00 some text 5.20 some text 5.29 some text
```

Regex pattern details:

```
(             Start capturing group
  0           Capturing group must start with a 0
  (?=         Start positive lookahead (meaning peek to the next character in the text)
    [^0-9.]   Make sure that the next character is not a digit or a dot
  )           End positive lookahead
)             End capturing group
```

Comment: Thanks lukas for the solution, and also for the detailed explanation, will definitely take some time to explore power of regex more in the future. You made my day, enjoy the rest of yours.

Comment: @Čendi Note that there are RegEx online test sites (for example https://regex101.com), they might prove helpful.